# Wrap dollar values in a span with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've got a bunch of h4 tags that I want to wrap in a `<span class="red"> </span>`

Some of the text is like this: $12 and some has a space like $ 5

How can I wrap all instances of $ and the numbers that follow with jQuery?

Let me clarify. I want to have this `<h4> this item is <span class="red">$42</span> and on sale</h4>`

Comment: Are you sure that you want to wrap `<h4>` in a span? That's invalid markup :)

Comment: Further to @Marko's comment, will the numbers always be integers, or will you need the same script to work with floats?

Comment: They will always be integers. I didn't realize that was invalid markup. I'll rework my tags so they are valid but for now just need to wrap $34 in a span.

Comment: It's invalid to have a block-level (`h2`) element inside an in-line element (`span`).

Comment: Let me clarify. I want to have this <h4> this item is <span class="red">$42</span> and on sale</h4>

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a regular expression. Something like:

```
var tempString = $("h4").html().replace(/^(.*)(\$\s*\d+)(.*)$/, '$1<span>$2</span>$3');
$("h4").html(tempString);
```

The regular expression might need some modification depending on your situation. In the second part of the replace, simply put the '$2' inside span tags with the class you want to add.

Comment: I don't know `'how to regular expression'` but I made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzZTG/). Really wish I know how. +1

Comment: Thanks, Reigel, for the fiddle that proved the regular expression I didn't actually test works!

Comment: the regex works, but the jQuery in your example will replace all `h4` elements with the same html. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmnHa/). You could go with either @Reigel's example or use jQuery's `each` function.

Comment: I assume you mean something like `$("h4").each(function() { ... })`

Comment: Yeah, I know I guess I assumed there would be only one h4 in my example. Use each()